# How to read Oracle Datafile .dbf using stings command in Unix

Tags: string, oracle, dbf, tde

I am in the process of implementing TDE in Oracle Database. I am trying to read the datafile using STRINGS command in UNIX but instead of displaying values the command is showing as below

```
$ strings tbs1pdbtde.dbf
}|{z
DBDEMO
TBS1PDBTDE

Instead of the above it should be showing:

DATE
DATE
DATE
DATE
DATE
DATE
```

What environment variable I have to set to display the output of STRINGS command?

Comment: Why do you expect it to show `DATE`?

Comment: And why do you think it should be showing the output you expected?  An oracle data file is far more complex in structure than would be indicated by getting useful information from a 'strings' command.

Comment: And stepping back, why do you think you'd get anything at useful with this operation - about anything at all, much less specifically about TDE.  Though now retired, I spent about 25 years working with oracle, from v 7.3 through 19c, and _never_ felt a need to run 'strings' against a dbf file.